# MOSFET current spec at Ta, Tc, Tj?

Tags: mosfet, thermal, maximum-ratings

When looking for a MOSFET on digi-key, I found that the current specification is given with temperature specifications, so one FET might be rated for 20 A (Ta) while another is rated for 20 A (Tc) and yet another 20 A (Tj), and many FETs have multiple of these ratings.

[image: A screenshot of digi-key, showing a bunch of FETs with different Ta/c/j after their current rating]

What temperature are they referring to here? I'm guessing ambient, case, and junction, but that doesn't tell me what temperature the spec is rated at--is it 25°C? The rated maximum temperature? Something else entirely? How can you even specify a specific ambient temperature without knowing the heatsinking and air forcing conditions anyway?

Comment: How about giving us a clue to the type of MOSFET and a link to it? I'm not sure how anyone can be expected to answer with so little information.

Comment: Pick one of those with multiple ratings; study its datasheet, and see if that helps explain how the multiple ratings arose. Note that the information in these "selection guide" searches is typed in by some minimum wage employee, and please don't be too hard on them if it's not precise...

Comment: @KevinWhite This is about how FETs are rated in Digi-key's system in general; almost *every* MOSFET here has a temperature attached to its current rating. Here, [take a look](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm not meaning to be hard on whoever's entering the data--I just want to know more about what this means, since from the sheer numbers I assume this is a standard practice. I see several datasheets specify it at 25°C, but is that a safe assumption in general?

Answer (score 2):

The current rating of a power Mosfet reported on the first page of its datasheet is usually calculated in the ideal condition of case temperature `Tc=25°C` and junction temperature `Tj=Tjmax`

The maximum power is limited by the `Thermal Resistance Junction to Case Rthjc`,
the `Tjmax` (usually 150°C or 175°C) and the ideal case temperature `Tc=25°C`

Pmax = Rdson(@Tjmax)*Ids^2 = (Tjmax-Tc)/Rthjc

and transforming

Ids=sqrt((Tjmax-Tc)/(Rthjc*Rdson(@Tjmax))

Usually datasheets include the `Maximum power` curve and the `Maximum current` curve
in function of Tc values between 25C and Tjmax.

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDB9403_F085-D.PDF

[image]

If the package is limiting the maximum current to a value lower than the calculated one,
the two values are reported as silicon limit and package limit.

The same calculation can be performed if we use the `Thermal Resistance Junction to Ambient` Rthja, but normally the values used are generic and seldom fit with the particular Heatsink used in an application.

Answer (score 1):

Having the link to the page, we can see the heading says:

> Current - Continuous Drain (Id) @ 25°C

but doesn't define which of Tc, Tj or Ta it refers to.

It's a crude attempt to make sense of info from different mfgs with different datasheet styles.

Taking the first FET, it'll support 20A at Ta=25C(under some unknown cooling conditions that are hopefully specified in the datasheet) or 92A at Tj=25C (if you can actually keep the junction down to that temperature!)

Comment: I thought it'd be something along these lines. It does make things somewhat difficult to compare. (and yes, I have no idea how you'd keep the junction at 25° with 92 amps through it, at least not without cryogenic cooling!)

Comment: Bolting it to the casing of an outboard motor in Scottish coastal waters would work! (and yes I am working on something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Each package has a thermal resistance Rjc Rca and Rja. The OEM data sheet specifies the parameters normally with an infinite heat sink at Tc=25’C , which then yields the maximum current spec.

Then a lower current spec might be given for no heat sink and just the ambient temp of Ta=25’C is sometimes given for showing the changes in leakage current or RdsOn for example.

Tj =90’C may be a recommended worst case design goal when the absolute max is 125’C where a lower temp improves reliability margin usually 50% MTBF for every ‘10C rise in junction temp above room temp or Ta=25’C just above room temp. (25’C was chosen as a universal test std. so it can be regulated on the device test set in an air conditioned room for measurement accuracy.)

You decide how much thermal margin you want and then interpolate the expected performance.  This filter criteria might not be useful at first glance , so it can often be ignored unless you know exactly what you need.